# SWT canvas not displaying an image when redrawn unless its 5x5 pixels

Tags: java, swt

I have the following UI layout in my window (SWT):

- Shell

  - TabFolder (FillLayout)
  - Composite (RowLayout (horizontal)

    - Group (RowLayout, vertical)

      - Label
      - Label
      - Text (width: 450)
      - Button
    - Group (RowLayout, vertical)

      - Label
      - Label
      - Canvas (this is the problem)

All the RowLayouts have the following attributes:

```
wrap = true, justify = true, pack = true, marginLeft = 0
```

The problem I have is, if I try to set any `Image` to the `canvas` (to be drawn when the `paint` event is called, using `event.gc.drawImage(0,0)` ), its usually not shown at all even though the paint event is called (I see the `System.out.println()` calls). If I set a 5pixel image and maximize the window, then the image is drawn, but it also calls the paint event like crazy, and the image continually flickers.

I am resizing the canvas after the image is set, using:

`canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().width);`

If I remove that, then the flickering and repeated `paint` calls are gone, however I still cannot show images any bigger than 5x5, they don't show at all.

What's going on here..? Should I switch to GridLayout? I essentially just want to show two groups, each will contain a vertical list of fields / canvases.

Code of my ImgCanvas class which is used for handling the showing of the image:

```
public class ImgCanvas
{
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Image img; 
    private int lastImgHash = 0;

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        initCanvas();
    }

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent, Image img)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        setImage(img);
        initCanvas();
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.initCanvas();
    }

    public void setImage(Image img)
    {
        if (this.img != null)
            this.img.dispose();
        this.img = img;

        System.out.println("Set image: " + img.getBounds() + ", " + img.toString());
        redraw();
    }

    public void redraw()
    {
        canvas.redraw();
    }

    protected void initCanvas()
    {
        System.out.println("Canvas started");
        canvas.addPaintListener( getPaintListener() );
        canvas.addDisposeListener( getDisposeListener() );
    }

    protected PaintListener getPaintListener()
    {
        return new PaintListener()
        {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Painting");
                if (img != null )
                {
                    System.out.println("Img:" + img.getBounds() );
                    e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    //canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().width);
                    //canvas.pack();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Img is null: " + img);
            }
        };
    }

    protected DisposeListener getDisposeListener()
    {
        return new DisposeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Disposing");
                if (img != null)
                    img.dispose();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is set in the following way:

```
imgCanvas = new ImgCanvas(group2); //2nd group in the layout given above.
```

Then later, in the click handler of the button in group 1 (selectionHandler), the following is done:

```
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
        //get a screenshot of a particular screen region using Java.Awt.Robot.captureScreenRegion,
        //convert the image into a SWT image, and try to show it:
        Image screenshot = ImgUtility.getScreenShot(0,0,10,10); 
        imgCanvas.setImage(screenshot);
        System.out.println("redrawn");
    }
```

Comment: can you please add code in question?

Comment: Ok then please do not add the code. I would recommend, use following parameters while creating canvas `objCanvas =new Canvas(parent, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);`

Comment: @ShishirPandey I have added some code...

Comment: @ShishirPandey Thanks for that, the flickering is gone now, but the problem is that the image is not being displayed at all unless its 5x5 pixels and i have maximized the page.

Comment: Ok thanks for code. I am trying to reproduce problem at my end. I will revert back in sometime.

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. Paint event is being called recursively when you are calling setSize within PaintListener. You need to set the size outside paintlistener, this will avoid flickering. Can't you set size in SetImage method? `public void setImage(Image img)
    {
        if (this.img != null)
            this.img.dispose();
        this.img = img;
        canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);
        canvas.pack();
        System.out.println("Set image: " + img.getBounds() + ", " + img.toString());
        redraw();
    }`

Comment: @ShishirPandey But the setSize line is already commented. Like I said, the flickering problem is solved, the problem now is that the image is not being shown at all, probably because of RowLayout, its not being given enough room to be displayed.

Comment: I have added code of 2 java files. demo.java and ImgCanvas.java. Please have look. This code allow resize of composite based on image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo.java

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot.*;

public class Demo {

    static Spinner s;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    FillLayout layout= new FillLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    Composite comp=new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER_DOT);
    RowLayout r1=new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    r1.wrap=true;
    r1.justify=true;
    r1.pack=true;
    r1.marginLeft=0;

    RowLayout r2=new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
    r2.wrap=true;
    r2.justify=true;
    r2.pack=true;
    r2.marginLeft=0;

    comp.setLayout(r1);
    Group grp1;


    grp1= new Group(comp,SWT.BORDER_DASH);
    grp1.setLayout(r2);
    Label l11,l22;
    Text txt;
    Button btn;

    l11=new Label(grp1, SWT.NONE);
    l11.setText("Label1");
    l22=new Label(grp1, SWT.NONE);
    l22.setText("Label2");
    txt= new Text(grp1, SWT.BORDER);
    btn= new Button(grp1, SWT.PUSH);

    Group grp2;


    Label l1,l2;
    grp2= new Group(comp,SWT.BORDER);
    grp2.setLayout(r2);

    //grp2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    l1= new Label(grp2, SWT.NONE);
    l1.setText("lable1");

    l2= new Label(grp2, SWT.NONE);
    l2.setText("lable1");

    final ImgCanvas imgCanvas = new ImgCanvas(grp2);


    //shell.redraw();
//  shell.setSize(600, 600);
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();

    btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
            //get a screenshot of a particular screen region using Java.Awt.Robot.captureScreenRegion,
            //convert the image into a SWT image, and try to show it:
            Image screenshot = new Image(display, "c:\\temp\\imgmsg.png"); 
            imgCanvas.setImage(screenshot);
            System.out.println("redrawn");

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }  }}
```

and below is ImgCanvas.Java

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class ImgCanvas
{
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Image img; 
    private int lastImgHash = 0;

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        initCanvas();
    }

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent, Image img)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
       // canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
     //   canvas.layout();
        setImage(img);
        initCanvas();
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.initCanvas();
    }

    public void setImage(Image img)
    {
        if (this.img != null)
            this.img.dispose();
        this.img = img;

       // canvas.pack();
      // canvas.getParent().getParent().layout();
      //  canvas.getParent().getParent().getParent().layout();
        canvas.getParent().setSize(img.getBounds().width,canvas.getParent().getSize().y);
        canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);



        System.out.println("Set image: " + img.getBounds() + ", " + img.toString());
        redraw();
    }

    public void redraw()
    {
        canvas.redraw();
    }

    protected void initCanvas()
    {
        System.out.println("Canvas started");
        canvas.addPaintListener( getPaintListener() );
        canvas.addDisposeListener( getDisposeListener() );
    }

    protected PaintListener getPaintListener()
    {
        return new PaintListener()
        {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Painting");
                if (img != null )
                {
                    System.out.println("Img:" + img.getBounds() );
                    e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                 //   canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().width);
                 //   canvas.pack();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Img is null: " + img);
            }
        };
    }

    protected DisposeListener getDisposeListener()
    {
        return new DisposeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Disposing");
                if (img != null)
                    img.dispose();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: it has no effect. I've even switched to GridLayout now, and still the same. In the `paintControl` method I added this line: `System.out.println("Canvas: " + canvas.getBounds() );`. Now the output is: `Img:Rectangle {0, 0, 61, 30} Canvas: Rectangle {0, 0, 64, 64}`. But despite of this the image is not being shown.

Comment: If you test this yourself, are you able to easily set the image when the button is clicked and have it show properly on the form? If so, can I see your code where this is working please?

Comment: Shishir do you have skype so we can pick each other's mind on SWT related things?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have skype. :( my email id is updated in stackoverflow profile. We can get in touch using emails.

Comment: No chat or IM programs?

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout data for the `Canvas` to a `RowData` instance with the `width` and `height` fields set to the size of the image.

Comment: I've now switched to GridLayout, and I tried providing GridData with the height and width, but it has no effect. :(